# Get first attribute from link element

Tags: javascript

There's a small issue I'm running trough. I have this link element.

```
<a href="/web_send_message_widget.php?recipient_id=123456789">Message</a>
```

That's what is displayed when no user is logged in and readresses the user to the login page.
But if the user is logged in already, this is displayed.

```
<a href="#" onlick="messagePopupShow({force_recipient_id:123456789}); return false;">Message</a>
```

I'm trying to get the `123456789` ID number in both cases. The link element does not change position in the DOM, but the attribute is different.

And then also split the result to get just the ID number in both cases?

If possible, all done in pure JavaScript.

Comment: This “attribute order” only exists in the HTML code, it does not exist in DOM. (And besides that, the part you say you are interested in is the _second_ attribute in your second HTML snippet – if you were to actually look for the “first” one, you would only get the `#` of the `href` attribute.) So your whole question makes little sense.

Comment: In the first case you want "/web_send..." and in the second you want to get the "#" value?  I think you could use some anchor = document.getElement... method and, the anchor.href value should hold what you want.

Comment: ...true that. I honestly copleatly skipped over the first href="#".
I guess my issue has no possibility.

Comment: I don't know what you are using to render your HTML, but is it possible for you to add a "data-" attribute to your element with the value you want to grab?

Comment: The HTML is rendered by a host that's not mine. Or else I would. But eitherway 90% of the users that do check the website are logged in, so I'll stick to `onClick` and if the user is not I'll give an `alert();`
I just wanted to know if it was possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pure Javascript, I would do something like:

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    if (anchors[i].getAttribute('href')){
        var m = anchors[i].getAttribute('href').match(/[?&]+recipient_id=(\d+)/);
        if (m && m.length > 1){
           return m[1];
        }
    }

    if (anchors[i].getAttribute('onclick')){
        var m = anchors[i].getAttribute('onclick').match(/force_recipient_id:(\d+)/);
        if (m && m.length > 1){
           return m[1];
        }
    }
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kQe5q/)**

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be best to check for both cases, since you know the cases (`href` or `onclick`), and you may not always be able to guarantee that it will be the first attribute specified in an `a` tag. If any of the pages were to be updated in the future, etc.

Here's what I would recommend:

```
function getRecipientId(a) {
  // look for the recipientId in the href
  var matches = $(a).attr('href').match(/^.*recipient_id=(\d+)/);
  if (matches && matches.length > 0) {
    return matches[1];
  }

  // look for the recipientId in the onclick
  var matches = $(a).attr('onclick').match(/^.*force_recipient_id:(\d+)/);
  if (matches && matches.length > 0) {
    return matches[1];
  }

  return false;
}
```

And you would call it like this: `getRecipient('a#linkId');`.

This way you can also easily add other cases in the future, and you're free from having to ensure that the recipient_id is always in the first attribute on every link.

Cheers!